# Bootstrap script preventing changing colors (and maybe more...)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using "Sublime" and I'm using bootstrap 3.3 (as the author in my course) and I tried to put the bootstrap as a script instead as a file, and when I've tried to change jumbotron class's color, it didn't respond.

When I checked my code in codepen without the bootstrap script (because it's installed already),the color changing works fine.

Any one knows way ?

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/XqOxyx) and part of my code:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span> The Image Gallery</h1> 
    <p>Wallcome to this beautiful images gallery</p>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
body {

    padding-top: 70px;

}
.navbar-inverse {
    color: #2C2E41;
}  

.jumbotron {

    color: #2C2E41;
}
```

Comment: Where and in what file is your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are not able to change the style of your website, for that you need to link them properly. As, you seem to be a beginner, I suggest you to keep the html file and css file in the same directory and then do the following,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7">
<link src="style.css">
```

Link those files in this order and then try editing your styles.
If it still doesn't work then you can also use,

```
.jumbotron {
background-color: #c3c3c3 !important;
}
```

But proper order of linking works fine.

Comment: Brilliant! How I've forget this one?! SO that means that there's an element with higher specificity there ? And if so, how can I find it with the "inspector tool" ?

Comment: Well, inspector tool is very specific, it shows very clearly which code the website is using, for example,
[this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfcImZIx1fbccPbkkt9PyPmKlhm6dI674DFwRXCih0Sj-NcEEssbFJV9N6jA) and you can use google for more detailed information.

Comment: So maybe you know how to bypass this problem that I need to use in EVERY  font syntax "!important" or less it wouldn't work, every thing else in the bootstrap, like grid, container etc' works fine and right now my code looks like that: h1 {

 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 700 !important;
 color: white !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Where is your css? You'll need to add that to your html *after* you import the bootstrap CDN, as stylesheets are 'cascading' - meaning that they are applied in the order that they are reached.

Eg.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" src="{YOUR STYLESHEET HERE}" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? In the Sublime I used :                                        <!-- Bootstarp CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Where are you changing the color of the jumbotron class? That's not in the code that you have shown @NadavHimmelfarb

Comment: It's in the codepen - I'll add it right now, thank you. About Bootstrap, so I need 2 links, 1-for the url 2-for the location on my computer? Have I understood you correctly ?

Comment: That is correct, otherwise how does your html know to change anything with your css file? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` - where 'styles.css' is the name of your local stylesheet and at a relative path to your html

Comment: I've1.Download the file  2.Copied the url and put them both in my editor like that:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap337.min.css" /> And when I inspected my code I've got the message: Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: file:///C:/Users/Nadav/Desktop/Udeamy/bootstrap337.min.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map

Comment: Nadav, I think you might need to go and watch a few tutorials on how to setup an html and css file. Just having the files open in sublime is not how they work. Sublime won't automatically add css to an html file. You will need to know the folder structure of your html and css and you need to include the css file in your html - this is well beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Ok I'll do that, thank you very much for your time :)